# Server returning 400 when user exists

Tags: http, go, testing

I'm working on some tests in Go and I have spent the past 2 days trying to make it work but I couldn't. My problem is that the test returns 400 even when the user does exist.

This is my getUser function

```
func (handler *UserHandler) getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, ID int) {
    logfile, err := os.OpenFile("events.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer logfile.Close()
    log.SetOutput(logfile)

    user := db.Fetch(ID)

    userJSON, err := json.Marshal(user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while marshaling the user into JSON: %v", err)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    // userJSON is sent as http Response
    w.Write(userJSON)
}
```

This is my UserHandler

```
type UserHandler struct{}

func (handle *UserHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var head string
    head, r.URL.Path = ShiftPath(r.URL.Path)
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(head)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Invalid user ID %q", head), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
        handle.getUser(w, id)
    default:
        http.Error(w, "Only GET is allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
}

func ShiftPath(p string) (head, tail string) {
    p = path.Clean("/" + p)
    i := strings.Index(p[1:], "/") + 1
    if i <= 0 {
        return p[1:], "/"
    }
    return p[1:i], p[i:]
}
```

And this is my test

```
func TestGetUser(t *testing.T) {
    handler := new(UserHandler)
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/user/", handler.ServeHTTP)

    writer := httptest.NewRecorder()
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/user/12", nil)
    mux.ServeHTTP(writer, request)

    if writer.Code != 200 {
        t.Errorf("Response code is %v", writer.Code)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `net/http/httptest` for testing your server, that's what its for. [example](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server)

Comment: @mkopriva: the question mentions httptest in one of the code snippets

Comment: @EliBendersky my bad, I've completely overlooked that one, although what I meant, and linked to, is the use of the [httptest.Server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server) instead of the "naked" mux.

Comment: What is the response body? Looks like the only place you respond 400 is if the `Atoi` fails, and you include some useful info in the body but you don't record it in your test.

Comment: @Adrian You're right. The problem is from the `Atoi` function. For some reason it fails every time. Any idea why that could be? I've never seen `Atoi` fail before. I have looked at what is passed to it and it is `"10"`

Comment: It's definitely not being passed `"10"`, because in that case it would not be returning an error: https://play.golang.org/p/TeX1JVDN4wE

Comment: Check to make sure there's no whitespace or unprintable characters before/after the digits.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/GiQi3UZQbjN Neither path, nor head, are valid inputs for Atoi. You need to fix your shiftpath function.

Comment: Oh I got it now. The weird thing is that it work well when I'm getting the user data through my browser, but it doesen't when I'm testing

Answer (score 0):

Issue with code ====> id, err := strconv.Atoi(head)
Due to error you see a return and hence you see 400 error.

Have your server code fully functional with valid logic.

Suggestion: Always print or debug line by line. You can find the issue and root cause.